# How does a Visual Studio Add-in receive notification of user input events?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I am taking my first crack at building a Visual Studio add-in (using C#).  When the add-in is enabled, I want it to execute some code in response to a a sequence of keyboard input (e.g. CTRL + ALT + P...or whatever).  Unfortunately, every time I find a method in Microsoft's documentation that I *think* might work, I find that it is commented as being for "Microsoft Internal Use Only".

Thanks in advance your suggestions.

To clarify what I mean by "Add-in", please see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80493a3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What do you mean add-in? For the IDE or are you talking about Microsoft's .NET libraries? Can you give some specific examples?

Comment: Visual Studio IDE.  I edited the question to include a link to the type of "add-on" I am building.

Comment: OK, now that we cleared up exactly what your talking about ;) Whats the question exactly?

Comment: Simply, how does an add-on register to receive keyboard input events...?

Comment: Did you look at msdn's information at all? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5x1f46hd.aspx